# Using Devel::NYTProf on program that fork/execs

Tags: perl, exec, fork, devel-nytprof

First I `export PERL5OPT=-d:NYTProf` from the command line so that my debugging option will be inherited by child processes.  Then I launch my Perl program **contactd**.  It forks to become a daemon process, and then fork/execs nine instances of another Perl program, **table_manager**.  (The exec looks something like `exec /path/to/perl /path/to/table_manager`.)  At this point I can see 10 or 11 new files called **nytprof.out.*nnnn***; one for each process that has been forked up til now, as expected.

Clients connect to **contactd** which fork/execs **slave**, which in turn connects to the nine table managers and accepts requests from the client and passes them to the nine table managers.

After running a typical client connection, I shut down all the server processes.  I run **nytprofmerge** to merge the various **nytprof.out.*nnnn*** files into **nytprof-merged.out**, and then run `nytprofhtml -f nytprof-merged.out --open`.

When the HTML report opens, I see no mention of anything but **contactd**.  The top subroutines are mostly BEGIN blocks, **import**, **AUTOLOAD** ... early execution stuff.

This leads me to think that NYTPROF *is* going across a fork (based on the multiple nytprof.out files) but for some reason is not continuing to profile the **exec**'ed Perl programs.

I'm running perl 5.16.1 and the latest Devel::NYTProf, in MacOSX 10.8.2.

Any suggestions as to what I've not done?

Answer (score 3):

You could set fork depth variable to -1:

http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.25/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm#forkdepth=N

> forkdepth=N
>
> When a perl process that is being profiled executes a fork() the child
>   process is also profiled. The forkdepth option can be used to control
>   this. If forkdepth is zero then profiling will be disabled in the
>   child process.
>
> If forkdepth is greater than zero then profiling will be enabled in
>   the child process and the forkdepth value in that process is
>   decremented by one.
>
> If forkdepth is -1 (the default) then there's no limit on the number
>   of generations of children that are profiled.

Regards,

Comment: I have had to try this at work, on a different OS (CentOS), and there are some differences.  I had to explicitly specify the *addpid=1* option in order to get NYTPROF to append pid to the .out files.  (This seemed to happen automatically in my OSX environment.)  And I got everything I wanted, without specifying forkdepth=-1 (which is the default, anyway).  So I'll have to try this tonight on OSX and see if specifying addpid is the answer, or if forkdepth makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you forgot a first nytprof.out to merge.
You could merge it or you can pass addpid=1 option to always get nytprof.out.nnnn even for first entry.